# airflow schedule issue - diff between schedule time and run time

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I set the schedule like '* 1,5,10,18 * * *' in airflow.
But 18 in yesterday wasn't executed. So I checked the logs.
then I found the job scheduled in 10 executed in 18.
I want to know why and how can I fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
> stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
> other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has
> ended.

~[Airflow scheduler docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html)

So as you can see it will be scheduled after the period - `10->18` is closed, so after 18:00. Check task before, it should be ran just after 10:00.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how the airflow scheduler works.

Airflow as DAG Run (data_interval_start) always takes the date of the previous execution, therefore the task performed at your place at 18, has DAG Run at 10. The same as the next task, call at 10 will have a DAG Run at 18 the previous day.